# Dynamic choice of variable by a function in Dart (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building my first app with Flutter, here's the problem I stuck with:
I have several tabs with radio buttons, the tabs are generated dynamically. I am using two functions to handle the changes in those radio buttons. Each function is used in every tab. 
My problem is that I don't know how to assign the value of the radio buttons to different variables.
I precreated the variables, but how do I access them from my functions? I tried do do it this way:

```
var bedsRoom1, bedsRoom2... bedsRoom7; //7 variables which is maximum of what I need
```

I use the functions as a callback inside the state of the stateful widget. Inside the function I tried to do:

```
  void _handleRadioValueChange1(int value, int counter) {
    setState(() {
      _radioValue1 = value;
      bedsRoom$counter = value;
    });
  }
```

I get error messages about an undefined name of a variable. Please explain how to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring multiple variables, you can declare a list of variables like this -

```
List bedRooms = new List(7);
```

Then you can access the variables like this -

```
void _handleRadioValueChange1(int value, int counter) {
setState(() {
  _radioValue1 = value;
  bedsRooms[counter] = value;
});
```

}

You can read more about List in dart from here - 
[Lists in dart](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/List-class.html)